# How to delete UI themes that I installed from disk in JetBrains product?

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide

Once I have installed few UI themes from disk and now I see them in my "Color Scheme" tab even when I did complete uninstall of IntelliJ IDEA (I removed all files from folder like "Logs", "Preferences" etc in ~/Library folder), but this UI themes still appear!

I am using latest versions of macOS and IntelliJ IDEA.

[image: img]

On the screenshot last two UI themes are custom ones that I want to delete.

How may I accomplish it?

Thanks!

Comment: How about Settings | find "color scheme" ...?

Comment: @Meo now we are talking! You can move to "Answers" and I will mark it as solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to `File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme` and remove it